# how to get Grand Total of Wishlish Items in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist, grand-total, items

i am trying to get grand total of wishlist item. when we update quantity of wishlist item then total will show in price column and display the all item grand total at bottom. anybody knows answer please help me. your help will be appreciated.

app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\wishlist\item\list.phtml

```
<?php
$columns = $this->getColumns();
?>
<table class="clean-table linearize-table" id="wishlist-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <?php
            /* @var $column  Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist_Item_Column */
            foreach ($columns as $column):
                $_blockName = str_replace('.','-',strtolower($column->getNameInLayout()));
        ?>
            <th class="<?php echo $_blockName; ?>"><?php echo $column->getTitle();?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php if (count($this->getItems())): ?>
        <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $item): ?>
            <tr id="item_<?php echo $item->getId();?>">
                <?php
                    foreach ($columns as $key => $column):
                        $_blockName = str_replace('.','-',strtolower($column->getNameInLayout()));

                        /* Override default column title in layout, useful for certain cases like select all box */
                        if ($column->getRwdTitle()) {
                            $_rwdLabel = $column->getRwdTitle();
                        } else {
                            $_rwdLabel = ($column->getTitle()) ? $column->getTitle() : false;
                        }
                ?>
                    <td class="<?php echo 'wishlist-cell'.$key; ?> <?php echo $_blockName; ?>"<?php if($_rwdLabel): ?> data-rwd-label="<?php echo $_rwdLabel; ?>"<?php endif; ?>><?php $column->setItem($item); echo $column->toHtml($item);?></td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <td colspan="<?php echo count($columns);?>" class="wishlist-empty"><?php echo $this->__('This quote has no Items');?></td>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
 </table>
   <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
   <?php echo $column->getAdditionalHtml();?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
   decorateTable('wishlist-table');

  <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
   <?php echo $column->getJs();?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  //]]>
```

Comment: I think you have to work on loops to get the total of wishlist there is no core function for getting the total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by updating following file.
**app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_THEME\template\wishlist\item\list.phtml**
replace your file code with below.

```
<?php
$columns = $this->getColumns();
$wishListTotal = 0;
?>
<table class="clean-table linearize-table" id="wishlist-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <?php
            /* @var $column  Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist_Item_Column */
            foreach ($columns as $column):
                $_blockName = str_replace('.','-',strtolower($column->getNameInLayout()));
        ?>
            <th class="<?php echo $_blockName; ?>"><?php echo $column->getTitle();?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php if (count($this->getItems())): ?>
        <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $item): 
                    $_product = $item->getProduct();
                    $_priceIncludingTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice());
                    $wishListTotal += $item->getQty() * $_priceIncludingTax;?>
            <tr id="item_<?php echo $item->getId();?>">
                <?php
                    foreach ($columns as $key => $column):
                        $_blockName = str_replace('.','-',strtolower($column->getNameInLayout()));

                        /* Override default column title in layout, useful for certain cases like select all box */
                        if ($column->getRwdTitle()) {
                            $_rwdLabel = $column->getRwdTitle();
                        } else {
                            $_rwdLabel = ($column->getTitle()) ? $column->getTitle() : false;
                        }
                ?>
                    <td class="<?php echo 'wishlist-cell'.$key; ?> <?php echo $_blockName; ?>"<?php if($_rwdLabel): ?> data-rwd-label="<?php echo $_rwdLabel; ?>"<?php endif; ?>><?php $column->setItem($item); echo $column->toHtml($item);?></td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <td colspan="<?php echo count($columns);?>" class="wishlist-empty"><?php echo $this->__('This quote has no Items');?></td>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
<tfoot style="border-top:1px solid #c0c0c0;">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="product-name a-right"><?php echo $this->__("Grand Total");?></th>
        <td class="product-name cart-cell"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($wishListTotal, true, false); ?></th>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
 </table>
   <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
   <?php echo $column->getAdditionalHtml();?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
   decorateTable('wishlist-table');

  <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
   <?php echo $column->getJs();?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  //]]>
</script>
```

**ADD SUBTOTAL COLUMN**

Open **app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\wishlist.xml** and
Replace `<wishlist_index_index>` tag with below code.

```
<wishlist_index_index translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account My Wishlist</label>
    <!-- Mage_Wishlist -->
    <update handle="customer_account" />
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist" name="customer.wishlist" template="wishlist/view.phtml">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                <title>My Wishlist</title>
            </action>
            <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_items" name="customer.wishlist.items" as="items" template="wishlist/item/list.phtml">
                <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_image" name="customer.wishlist.item.image" template="wishlist/item/column/image.phtml" />
                <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_comment" name="customer.wishlist.item.info" template="wishlist/item/column/info.phtml">
                    <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_button" name="customer.wishlist.button.update" template="wishlist/button/update.phtml" />
                </block>
                <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.quantity" template="wishlist/item/column/quantity.phtml">
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                        <title>Qty</title>
                    </action>
                    <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_options" name="customer.wishlist.item.options" />
                </block>
                <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.price" template="wishlist/item/column/price.phtml">
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                        <title>Price</title>
                    </action>
                    <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_options" name="customer.wishlist.item.options" />
                </block>
                <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.subtotal" template="wishlist/item/column/subtotal.phtml">
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                        <title>Sub Total</title>
                    </action>
                    <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_options" name="customer.wishlist.item.options" />
                </block>
                <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.cart" template="wishlist/item/column/cart.phtml">
                    <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_options" name="customer.wishlist.item.options" />
                </block>
                <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_remove" name="customer.wishlist.item.remove" template="wishlist/item/column/remove.phtml" />
            </block>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="customer.wishlist.buttons" as="control_buttons">
                <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_button" name="customer.wishlist.button.share" template="wishlist/button/share.phtml" />
                <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_button" name="customer.wishlist.button.toCart" template="wishlist/button/tocart.phtml" />
                <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_button" name="customer.wishlist.button.update" template="wishlist/button/update.phtml" />
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>wishlist_customer_sidebar</name></action>
    </reference>
</wishlist_index_index>
```

Now create a new file **app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\wishlist\item\column\subtotal.phtml** with below code.

```
<?php
$item = $this->getItem();
$product = $item->getProduct();
$options = $this->getChild('customer.wishlist.item.options')
    ->setItem($item)
    ->getConfiguredOptions();
$_product = $item->getProduct();
$_priceIncludingTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice());
$wishListTotal = $item->getQty() * $_priceIncludingTax;
?>
<div class="cart-cell">
    <div class="price-box">
        <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $item->getId(); ?>">
            <span class="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($wishListTotal, true, false);?></span>
        </span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: it showing only grand total i need to show product list also

Comment: @Neeya You mean you need to add a new column which will show sub total of product price and its quantities?

Comment: see my list.phtml file update your answer in that

Comment: @Neeya, Please check updated answer. Also, do you need to add a new column which will show sub total of product price and its quantities?

Comment: quantity is already showing only need to show subtotal

Comment: how to add subtotal column

Comment: @Neeya, Please check updated code.

Comment: its completely works for me. thank you so much. your answer is accepted.

Comment: please go through this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186747/how-to-download-wishlist-list-item-as-a-pdf-in-magento  it posted by me. if you have any idea  about this please share.

Comment: @Neeya, I have checked your reference question and I think it will take more effort to achieve what you want, I will add an answer if I get any solution for your question.

Comment: there will be a button on wishlist item list page as "export as PDF" after clicking on this button i wants to download wishlist item list as a pdf format as it is.

Comment: How to show tax percentage of each product of wishlist?

Comment: if you know the answer please answer to this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192377/display-tax-rate-of-each-wishlist-in-magento  your help will be appriciated.

Comment: you have added subtotal column in wishlist now i have to add tax percentage like same. how can i do that? please help me.

Comment: hi please tell me how to display grand total including tax

Comment: if you know the solution  please answer to this question  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193406/how-to-show-grand-total-of-wishlist-item-list-incluging-tax