# How to download wishlist list item as a PDF in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist, items, download

I would like to download wishlist items in PDF format.

there will be a button on wishlist item list page as "export as PDF" after clicking on this button i wants to download wishlist item list as a pdf format as it is.

*app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\wishlist\item\list.phtml*

```
<?php
$columns = $this->getColumns();
$wishListTotal = 0;
?>
<table class="clean-table linearize-table" id="wishlist-table">
<thead>
<tr>
<?php
    /* @var $column  Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist_Item_Column */
    foreach ($columns as $column):
        $_blockName = str_replace('.','-',strtolower($column->getNameInLayout()));
?>
    <th class="<?php echo $_blockName; ?>"><?php echo $column->getTitle();?></th>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php if (count($this->getItems())): ?>
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $item): 
            $_product = $item->getProduct();
            $_priceIncludingTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice());
            $wishListTotal += $item->getQty() * $_priceIncludingTax;?>
    <tr id="item_<?php echo $item->getId();?>">
        <?php
            foreach ($columns as $key => $column):
                $_blockName = str_replace('.','-',strtolower($column->getNameInLayout()));

                /* Override default column title in layout, useful for certain cases like select all box */
                if ($column->getRwdTitle()) {
                    $_rwdLabel = $column->getRwdTitle();
                } else {
                    $_rwdLabel = ($column->getTitle()) ? $column->getTitle() : false;
                }
         ?>
            <td class="<?php echo 'wishlist-cell'.$key; ?> <?php echo $_blockName; ?>"<?php if($_rwdLabel): ?> data-rwd-label="<?php echo $_rwdLabel; ?>"<?php endif; ?>><?php $column->setItem($item); echo $column->toHtml($item);?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <td colspan="<?php echo count($columns);?>" class="wishlist-empty"><?php echo $this->__('This quote has no Items');?></td>
  <?php endif; ?>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot style="border-top:1px solid #c0c0c0;">
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="product-name a-right"><?php echo $this->__("Grand Total");?></th>
<td class="product-name cart-cell"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($wishListTotal, true, false); ?></th>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   </tfoot>
   </table>
  <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
  <?php echo $column->getAdditionalHtml();?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
 decorateTable('wishlist-table');

   <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
   <?php echo $column->getJs();?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
  //]]>
 </script>
```

anybody knows solution Please help....

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868466/generate-pdf-of-wishlist-items-in-magento

Comment: i already tried this but not showing anything. i think only controller is not enough for this.

Comment: @mizuti it is not working please suggest another one