# How to show grand total of wishlist item list incluging tax?

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, wishlist, grand-total

I wants to show grand total including tax. i have follow this link to show grand total without tax [how to get Grand Total of Wishlish Items in magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184235/how-to-get-grand-total-of-wishlish-items-in-magento#184247) and it working fine. but i need to display grand total of wishlist item including tax. please help.

This is my list.phtml file

```
<?php
$columns = $this->getColumns();
$wishListTotal = 0;
?>
<table class="clean-table linearize-table" id="wishlist-table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <?php
        /* @var $column  Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist_Item_Column */
        foreach ($columns as $column):
            $_blockName = str_replace('.','-',strtolower($column->getNameInLayout()));
    ?>
        <th class="<?php echo $_blockName; ?>"><?php echo $column->getTitle();?></th>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php if (count($this->getItems())): ?>
    <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $item): 
                $_product = $item->getProduct();
                $_priceIncludingTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice());
                $wishListTotal += $item->getQty() * $_priceIncludingTax;?>
        <tr id="item_<?php echo $item->getId();?>">
            <?php
                foreach ($columns as $key => $column):
                    $_blockName = str_replace('.','-',strtolower($column->getNameInLayout()));

                    /* Override default column title in layout, useful for certain cases like select all box */
                    if ($column->getRwdTitle()) {
                        $_rwdLabel = $column->getRwdTitle();
                    } else {
                        $_rwdLabel = ($column->getTitle()) ? $column->getTitle() : false;
                    }
            ?>
                <td class="<?php echo 'wishlist-cell'.$key; ?> <?php echo $_blockName; ?>"<?php if($_rwdLabel): ?> data-rwd-label="<?php echo $_rwdLabel; ?>"<?php endif; ?>><?php $column->setItem($item); echo $column->toHtml($item);?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <td colspan="<?php echo count($columns);?>" class="wishlist-empty"><?php echo $this->__('This quote has no Items');?></td>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
<tfoot style="border-top:1px solid #c0c0c0;">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="product-name a-right"><?php echo $this->__("Grand Total");?></th>
    <td class="product-name cart-cell"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($wishListTotal, true, false); ?></th>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
 </table>
  <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
  <?php echo $column->getAdditionalHtml();?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
 decorateTable('wishlist-table');

<?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
 <?php echo $column->getJs();?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  //]]>
</script>
```

**updated**
This is my wishlist frontend view

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code,

```
<?php
$columns = $this->getColumns();
$wishListTotal = 0;
$wishListTotalExcTax = 0;
?>
<table class="clean-table linearize-table" id="wishlist-table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <?php
        /* @var $column  Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist_Item_Column */
        foreach ($columns as $column):
            $_blockName = str_replace('.','-',strtolower($column->getNameInLayout()));
    ?>
        <th class="<?php echo $_blockName; ?>"><?php echo $column->getTitle();?></th>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php if (count($this->getItems())): ?>
    <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $item): 
                $_product = $item->getProduct();
                $_priceIncludingTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), true);
                $_priceExcludingTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), false);
                $wishListTotal += $item->getQty() * $_priceIncludingTax;
                $wishListTotalExcTax += $item->getQty() * $_priceExcludingTax;
                ?>
        <tr id="item_<?php echo $item->getId();?>">
            <?php
                foreach ($columns as $key => $column):
                    $_blockName = str_replace('.','-',strtolower($column->getNameInLayout()));

                    /* Override default column title in layout, useful for certain cases like select all box */
                    if ($column->getRwdTitle()) {
                        $_rwdLabel = $column->getRwdTitle();
                    } else {
                        $_rwdLabel = ($column->getTitle()) ? $column->getTitle() : false;
                    }
            ?>
                <td class="<?php echo 'wishlist-cell'.$key; ?> <?php echo $_blockName; ?>"<?php if($_rwdLabel): ?> data-rwd-label="<?php echo $_rwdLabel; ?>"<?php endif; ?>><?php $column->setItem($item); echo $column->toHtml($item);?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <td colspan="<?php echo count($columns);?>" class="wishlist-empty"><?php echo $this->__('This quote has no Items');?></td>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
<tfoot style="border-top:1px solid #c0c0c0;">
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="product-name a-right"><?php echo $this->__("Grand Total");?></th>
    <td class="product-name cart-cell">
    <?php echo "EXCL TAX:<br />". Mage::helper('core')->currency($wishListTotalExcTax, true, false); ?><br />
    <?php echo "INCL TAX:<br />".  Mage::helper('core')->currency($wishListTotal, true, false); ?>
    </th>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
 </table>
  <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
  <?php echo $column->getAdditionalHtml();?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
 decorateTable('wishlist-table');

<?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
 <?php echo $column->getJs();?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: grand total not showing correct please have a look on updated screenshot

Comment: @Neeya, please check updated code.

Comment: your answer is working. your help is appreciated. thanks a lot.

Comment: please have a look on screenshot. see highlight area after adding your answer it shows some numbers. i am not getting why? can you please help me

Comment: @Neeya, sorry it was the debug code. Please try updated code.